# Jquery Multiselect : How to know which value was selected/deselected

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I have Multiselect dropdown. Whenever there is a select or deselect, I need to get the value.
I am using change event, but struggling to get which option was selected/deselected.

Answer (score 2):

```
//all options

var all=[];
$('#multiple').each(function(i, selected){ 
    all[i] = $(selected).text(); 
});

//selected options  
var foo = []; 
$('#multiple :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
    foo[i] = $(selected).text(); 
});

// unselected options
var de= $.grep(all, function(element) {
    return $.inArray(element, foo) !== -1;
});
```

In the `foo` array are the selected values

In the `de` array are the unselected values

Comment: I want the option which was selected or dselected, $('#city option:selected').attr('value')  returns all the selected values and not the current one

Comment: by this you get selected option

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#selectId').on('change',function(){ 
    console.log($(this).val());// this will give you an array
});
```

Comment: This returns all the selected values, and does not answer the original question about selected and deselected values