# Jquery, Chosen : How can I get the value that was removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Chosen Jquery, and I want to get the value that was deselected from the multi select list. Somehow I am not getting it. What I am doing wrong?

```
   $("#teachingOptions").chosen().change(function (evt, params) {

    if (params.selected) {
        var value = $("#teachingOptions option:selected").val(); // This is working fine
        alert(value)
        return;}

else{

var value = $("#teachingOptions option:selected").val();  //Problem lies here, This Does not returns the correct value.
      alert value;   
      return;

}
```

So when someone selects its working fine, but if someone deselects from the list of alreay selectd, it does not return the value, it says Undefined.

Comment: take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627643/jquery-multiselect-how-to-know-which-value-was-selected-deselected#18627671), it's not a complete solution, but it may help

Comment: In the example you mentioend, what is de?  var de = $.grep(all, function (element) {
                return $.inArray(element, foo) !== -1;
            });

Answer (score 0):

In fact when user deselects the value will be an empty string, so you need to store the previous value, and get it when it's deselected;

Note that `$("#teachingOptions option:selected").val();` returns the same value of `params.selected`

```
var oldValue = $("#teachingOptions");
$("#teachingOptions").chosen().change(function (evt, params) {
    var value = params.selected || ''; // if params.selected is empty use an empty string
    if (!params.selected) { // deselected
        // the value that was deselected is avaliable in oldValue variable
    }
    oldValue = value; // value changed, so update the stored value
    alert (value);
}
```

Comment: But a user can select many values, how will i know which value was un selected?

Comment: It is not clear in the question that it is a multiple select, I suggest you to edit both question title and text mentioning that is a multiple select. If I can figure out a solution I will edit the answer